# Why is filter method not working properly?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to save the names of the students who scored 80 or more in a variable, but I couldn't manage to do it with filter, it returns the whole object although I specified that I want it to print the key values of these objects only, which is the names of these students.

My code:

```
// Students names/scores
let students = [
    {name: "Ahmed" , score: 84},
    {name: "Samira" , score: 69},
    {name: "Dana" , score: 75},
    {name: "Basil" , score: 100},
    {name: "Fahad" , score: 91},
    {name: "Aljawhara" , score: 80},
    {name: "Fadi" , score: 70},
]


// Students who scored 80 or more using filter
let studentsScoredMoreThan80 = students.filter((item,index,array) => {
    if(item.score >= 80) return item.name;
})
console.log(studentsScoredMoreThan80);
```

This is what it prints:
[image]

How do I get just the names of the students who scored 80 or more?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Comment: [Duplicate](//google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+js+filter+doesn%E2%80%99t+return+individual+properties) of [use filter to return property values in an object](/q/31201262/4642212). Familiarize yourself with [how to access and process nested objects, arrays or JSON](/q/11922383/4642212) and how to use the [`Array`](//developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Static_methods) methods (both static and on prototype).

Answer (score 2):

Filter just filters the list, it doesn't project list items into a new structure.

What you're looking for is a combination of `filter` *and* `map`.  First filter your list:

```
let studentsScoredMoreThan80 = students.filter(item => item.score >= 80);
```

Then map the results to the new structure you want:

```
studentsScoredMoreThan80 = studentsScoredMoreThan80.map(item => item.name);
```

Answer (score 1):

Filter <s>removes elements from an array</s> starts with an array, keeps only some of its elements based on a condition, and returns a new array, leaving the original one untouched. It does nothing else. It expects `true` or `false` as a return value (meaning keep or discard), but you're returning `item.name` (which is truthy, so it works like `true`).

Then you need to transform a full `student` object into just a string (their name) using `map` :

```js
let students = [
    {name: "Ahmed" , score: 84},
    {name: "Samira" , score: 69},
    {name: "Dana" , score: 75},
    {name: "Basil" , score: 100},
    {name: "Fahad" , score: 91},
    {name: "Aljawhara" , score: 80},
    {name: "Fadi" , score: 70},
]


// Students who scored 80 or more using filter
let studentsScoredMoreThan80 = students
                                  .filter(student => student.score > 80)
                                  .map( student => student.name);

console.log(studentsScoredMoreThan80)
```

Comment: _"Filter removes elements from an array."_ weeeellll, strictly it doesn't remove _anything_.

Comment: Yeah, my bad, indeed. It returns a _new_ array based on the original one, minus the removed elements. Answer edited

Answer (score 0):

The return value of 'callback' in 'Array.filter' is converted to 'Boolean', if 'item.score >= 80' returns a string and is converted to 'true', otherwise 'undefined' is returned and is converted to 'false', if you just want `student.name`, use `Array.map(callback)`